# coreos docker-compose v2: exposed port filtered behind Firewall and unreachable

Tags: docker, docker-compose, firewall, coreos

I found a strange behavior regarding network port exposition between docker-compose vs docker, I mean I can not set up properly with the docker-compose

On my CoreOS VM running under Virtualbox I would like to set up 2 containers

1. the first is the mysql Database (Mysql)
2. the second is a web application image (myghost) build based on the ghost image

**A - Method that DOES work : with docker :**

command that I use to launch my 2 containers

```
docker build -t myghost .  
docker run -d --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -e MYSQL_DATABASE=ghost -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password -e MYSQL_USER=ghost -p 3306 mysql  
sudo docker run -d --link mysql --name ghost -p 80:2368 myghost
```

Port 80 is correctly exposed and I can connect from my host network

`nmap` scan from another vm shows the port 80 open  (`nmap -sT 192.168.1.25`)

```
Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-04-05 23:06 CEST
Nmap scan report for coreos1.home (192.168.1.25)
Host is up (0.000088s latency).
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
22/tcp    open  ssh
80/tcp    open  http
4001/tcp  open  newoak
32779/tcp open  sometimes-rpc21
MAC Address: 08:00:27:90:17:CF (Oracle VirtualBox virtual NIC)
```

Iptables configuration (`sudo iptables -L`) returns :

```
Chain DOCKER (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.19.0.2           tcp dpt:mysql
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.19.0.3           tcp dpt:2368
```

`sudo iptables -S` shows

```
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.2/32 ! -i br-282da314ef5d -o br-282da314ef5d -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.3/32 ! -i br-282da314ef5d -o br-282da314ef5d -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2368 -j ACCEPT
```

*NB: My Dockerfile to build myghost image only contains a copy of a js file*

**B - method that does NOT work: with docker-compose :**

here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
 mysql:
  image: mysql
  container_name: mysql
  ports:
   - "3306"
  environment:
   - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
   - MYSQL_DATABASE=ghost
   - MYSQL_USER=ghost
   - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
 myghost:
  build: ./myghost
  container_name: myghost
  depends_on:
   - mysql
  ports:
   - "80:2368"
  expose:
   - "80"
```

*NB in this configuration I try to use the expose: directive that does not change the issue*

I then launch a `docker-compose up --build -d`. **At first execution** the ghost webapp never starts properly (error connecting to database) , strange because my `docker-compose.yml` contains depends_on ...

docker inspect ghost container returns

> ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.19.0.2:3306
>
> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.19.0.2:3306

At second run the container starts

```
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             
STATUS              PORTS                          NAMES
945d75995d11        appghost_myghost    "/entrypoint.sh npm s"   21 minutes 
ago      Up 21 minutes       80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->2368/tcp   myghost
aea76509818e        mysql               "docker-entrypoint.sh"   25 minutes 
ago      Up 25 minutes       0.0.0.0:32776->3306/tcp        mysql

docker-compose ps
 Name               Command             State              Ports
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
myghost   /entrypoint.sh npm start      Up      0.0.0.0:80->2368/tcp, 80/tcp
mysql     docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld   Up      0.0.0.0:32776->3306/tcp
```

ping between the 2 containers is OK
However my web application is unreacheable and shows port 80 as **filtered** with a nmap scan

```
PORT      STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp    open     ssh
80/tcp    filtered http
32780/tcp filtered sometimes-rpc23
```

I also noticed this way `iptables -S` configuration looks like that (only the diff part)

```
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.2/32 ! -i br-282da314ef5d -o br-282da314ef5d -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.3/32 ! -i br-282da314ef5d -o br-282da314ef5d -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2368 -j ACCEPT
```

**More Information**

```
Docker version 1.12.6, build d5236f0  
Docker-compose version 1.11.2, build dfed245  
CoreOs 1298.7.0  
VirtualBox v5.1.8 / Bridged network configuration
uname -a: Linux coreos1 4.10.4-coreos-r1 #1 SMP Fri Mar 31 01:58:22 UTC 2017 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600K CPU @ 3.40GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Something strange I noticed that just a reboot of the CoreOS VM and a restart with docker-compose seems to solve that problem .. Someone could confirm the configuration is right or has already encountered that issue ?

Answer (score 0):

reboot coreOs when face this kind of issue resolve the problem